# Azure LUIS API utterance id is too large

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-language-understanding

We're running into an issue with the Azure LUIS API whenever an utterance is created, We're getting errors such as this:

"integer 2158563342 is too large or small for an Int32"

We expect an integer value from the API and the Azure SDK states to expect an integer, but we're now getting larger values that don't work as expected.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cognitiveservices.language.luis.authoring.models.labeltextobject?view=azure-dotnet

Did something change recently with the API or SDK that isn't formally updated yet on Microsoft's website? Or could this be a problem on Microsoft's side that will be fixed? Any help is appreciated.

You can go to the API reference site:
https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c0a/console

Or use the following API with your LUIS app:
[https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/api/v2.0/apps/{appid}/versions/{version}/examples?skip=0&take=100](https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/api/v2.0/apps/%7Bappid%7D/versions/%7Bversion%7D/examples?skip=0&take=100)

Comment: Try changing the ID datatype to be long instead of int32.

Comment: @MagedRefaat The Azure SDK provides this class "LabelTextObject" and the ID is int32 and can't be modified. A work-around is to bypass the SDK completely for this API endpoint until Microsoft provides an updated SDK that resolves this problem?

Comment: If you can wait for an updated SDK (which will be soon) please do, if not you can bypass the SDK as a temp solution.

Comment: @MagedRefaat Yes, we needed to bypass the SDK for this endpoint, since the issue was impacting several customers. We will revert back to the SDK once you confirm the issue has been resolved on your side.

Answer (score 0):

@Syed - This is a know issue reported [here.](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/18041)

The issue has been identified and expected to fixed with an ETA of the 1st week February.

Comment: thanks for the info, since the issue was impacting several customers so we were looking for a solution